# Is it possible to use custom mappers in cytoscape.js 2.0?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I can see that there is already support for direct mapping from a data attribute or a predefined linear mapping with mapData, is there a best-practice for using custom mapping functions?

http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#style/mappers

*i.e.* doing something like this:

```
    ...
    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node')
        .css({
          'width': function() { return nonLinearFunction(this.data("attr")); }
        })
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of function are you looking for?  For performance reasons, it's important that the stored style values are not truly "dynamic":  Mapper values are cached, and updated only on changes to data, for example.

It would be easier to add the kind of function you're looking for if it's something like a logarithmic function, some type of mathematical function, or similar.  The main thing to keep in mind is that a callback function for "custom mappers" is not performant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max! I was looking for a logarithmic function, but I don't know if this is going to be the final gradient mapper I would like to use yet -- have to experiment and see. That's why I asked if a custom function is available or not. I see the performance related issues, so I guess a good solution for now will be to calculate the values beforehand and use them as an input to the linear map -- simple transformation.